# PNG Image not show in ios hardware but display in ios simulator?

Tags: ios

I've C library which converts raw data into image, in ios simulator it does show the image but when I run it on hardware it does not display it (image file extension is .png) can someone let me know what could be the problem OR Am I missing something?

Comment: A common problem is that the device file system is case sensitive and the simulator file system is not case sensitive. Also, please see all related questions.

Comment: I cross checked the whole path for any mismatch but no there is no problem with that. It is happening in ios 7 only